# How to automate adding license key into hazelcast mancenter

Tags: bash, ansible, hazelcast

I am playing around with hazelcast, using aws cloudformation and ansible to spin up a cluster of two hazelcast nodes + a separate mancenter.

All documentation on the mancenter implies everything must be done manually by a user in a browser. However this is not ideal as we will have many environments and have a hardened ami provided to us every few weeks which we must update existing environment to.

What I am trying to do is create an ansible role that automatically creates the first admin user, and then adds the enterprise license into the mancenter.

I have successfully scripted the user creation (just http for now, baby steps)

```
- name: Check for first user
  uri:
    url: "http://{{ hazelcastmanagement_dns }}:8080/mancenter/user.do?operation=anyUser&_=1480397059541"
    method: GET
    return_content: no
  register: anyuser
  until: anyuser.json["anyUser"] is defined
  retries: 10
  delay: 5

- name: Register Admin user
  uri:
    url: "http://{{ hazelcastmanagement_dns }}:8080/mancenter/user.do?operation=signUp&username={{ hazelcastmanagement_user }}&password={{ hazelcastmanagement_password }}&confirmpassword={{ hazelcastmanagement_password }}&email={{ hazelcastmanagement_email }}&_=1479951949840"
    method: GET
    return_content: no
  register: result
  until: result.json["success"] is defined
  retries: 10
  delay: 5
  when: anyuser.json["anyUser"] == "false"
```

However I am having trouble successfully orchestrating the update license call.
In a browser, certain calls return the JSESSION ID, and HTTP 200's. When trying to emulate this in ansible however, I am always getting a 302, redirect to the login page.

I have pasted the tasks below that I am attempting.
These task examples do not contain many headers, however I have tried emulating every single header that a browser sends previously but had the same result.

```
- name: Call to update license unauthorized (returns set_cookie)
  uri:
    url: "http://{{ hazelcastmanagement_dns }}:8080/mancenter/main.do"
    method: POST
    return_content: yes
    body: "operation=savelicense_getLicenceInfo&key={{ hazelcast_license }} "
    status_code: 302
  register: cookie

- name: Login (302 ok because browser mirrors this result)
  uri:
    url: "http://{{ hazelcastmanagement_dns }}:8080/mancenter/j_spring_security_check"
    method: POST
    body: "j_username={{ hazelcastmanagement_user }}&j_password={{ hazelcastmanagement_password }}"
    return_content: yes
    status_code: 302
    HEADER_Cookie: "{{cookie.set_cookie}}"

- name: Call to update license authorized
  uri:
    url: "http://{{ hazelcastmanagement_dns }}:8080/mancenter/main.do"
    method: POST
    return_content: yes
    body: "operation=savelicense_getLicenceInfo&key={{ hazelcast_license }}"
    HEADER_Cookie: "{{cookie.set_cookie}}"
```

My ansible task logs are below, -vvvv
Hoping someone else has looked into this previously, could not find any questions related to it elsewhere however.
Ansible Log Output:

```
TASK [hazelcastmanagement_launch : Call to update license authorized] **********
task path: /app/esg/ansible/roles/hazelcastmanagement_launch/tasks/launch.yml:5
ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: root
hazelcast EXEC ( umask 22 && mkdir -p "$( echo /tmp/ansible-tmp-1480399947.07-7077332634698 )" && echo "$( echo /tmp/ansible-tmp-1480399947.07-7077332634698 )" )
hazelcast PUT /tmp/tmpBbuVj0 TO /tmp/ansible-tmp-1480399947.07-7077332634698/uri
hazelcast EXEC chmod a+r /tmp/ansible-tmp-1480399947.07-7077332634698/uri
hazelcast EXEC /bin/sh -c 'sudo -H -S -n -u esg /bin/sh -c '"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-lemxlebthsblahblahblahcevqzkafjdo; LANG=en_US.UTF-8 HTTP_PROXY=proxy.com LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8 HTTPS_PROXY=proxy.com no_proxy=proxy.com http_proxy=proxy.com https_proxy=proxy.com NO_PROXY=proxy.com LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/python /tmp/ansible-tmp-1480399947.07-7077332634698/uri'"'"''
hazelcast EXEC rm -f -r /tmp/ansible-tmp-1480399947.07-7077332634698/ > /dev/null 2>&1
ok: [hazelcast] => {"changed": false, "content": "", "content_length": "0", "expires": "Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT", "invocation": {"module_args": {"backup": null, "body": "operation=savelicense_getLicenceInfo&key=ENTERPRISELicense12341234123412341234123412341234", "body_format": "raw", "content": null, "creates": null, "delimiter": null, "dest": null, "directory_mode": null, "follow": false, "follow_redirects": "safe", "force": null, "force_basic_auth": false, "group": null, "method": "POST", "mode": null, "owner": null, "password": null, "regexp": null, "remote_src": null, "removes": null, "return_content": true, "selevel": null, "serole": null, "setype": null, "seuser": null, "src": null, "status_code": ["302"], "timeout": 30, "url": "http://internal-esg-aws.elb.amazonaws.com:8080/mancenter/main.do", "user": null, "validate_certs": true}, "module_name": "uri"}, "location": "http://internal-esg-aws.elb.amazonaws.com:8080/mancenter/login.jsp;jsessionid=dq0hzdvm2xm91r4h6eyef1l48", "redirected": false, "server": "Jetty(8.y.z-SNAPSHOT)", "set_cookie": "JSESSIONID=dq0hzdvm2xm91r4h6eyef1l48;Path=/mancenter;HttpOnly", "status": 302}


TASK [hazelcastmanagement_launch : Login] **************************************
task path: /app/app/ansible/roles/hazelcastmanagement_launch/tasks/launch.yml:14
ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: root
hazelcast EXEC ( umask 22 && mkdir -p "$( echo /tmp/ansible-tmp-1480399947.23-71435275964843 )" && echo "$( echo /tmp/ansible-tmp-1480399947.23-71435275964843 )" )
hazelcast PUT /tmp/tmpKhOI1y TO /tmp/ansible-tmp-1480399947.23-71435275964843/uri
hazelcast EXEC chmod a+r /tmp/ansible-tmp-1480399947.23-71435275964843/uri
hazelcast EXEC /bin/sh -c 'sudo -H -S -n -u app /bin/sh -c '"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-rfxrchqnblahblahblahhvryauidnf; LANG=en_US.UTF-8 HTTP_PROXY=proxy.com8 LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8 HTTPS_PROXY=proxy.com no_proxy=proxy.com  http_proxy=proxy.com  NO_PROXY=proxy.com LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/python /tmp/ansible-tmp-1480399947.23-71435275964843/uri'"'"''
hazelcast EXEC rm -f -r /tmp/ansible-tmp-1480399947.23-71435275964843/ > /dev/null 2>&1
ok: [hazelcast] => {"changed": false, "content": "", "content_length": "0", "invocation": {"module_args": {"HEADER_Cookie": "JSESSIONID=dq0hzdvm2xm91r4h6eyef1l48;Path=/mancenter;HttpOnly", "backup": null, "body": "j_username=admin&j_password=admin1", "body_format": "raw", "content": null, "creates": null, "delimiter": null, "dest": null, "directory_mode": null, "follow": false, "follow_redirects": "safe", "force": null, "force_basic_auth": false, "group": null, "method": "POST", "mode": null, "owner": null, "password": null, "regexp": null, "remote_src": null, "removes": null, "return_content": true, "selevel": null, "serole": null, "setype": null, "seuser": null, "src": null, "status_code": ["302"], "timeout": 30, "url": "http://internal-aws.elb.amazonaws.com:8080/mancenter/j_spring_security_check", "user": null, "validate_certs": true}, "module_name": "uri"}, "location": "http://internal-aws.elb.amazonaws.com:8080/mancenter/login.jsp?login_error=true", "redirected": false, "server": "Jetty(8.y.z-SNAPSHOT)", "status": 302}

TASK [hazelcastmanagement_launch : Call to update license authorized] **********
task path: /app/app/ansible/roles/hazelcastmanagement_launch/tasks/launch.yml:23
ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: root
hazelcast EXEC ( umask 22 && mkdir -p "$( echo /tmp/ansible-tmp-1480399947.38-137956022601151 )" && echo "$( echo /tmp/ansible-tmp-1480399947.38-137956022601151 )" )
hazelcast PUT /tmp/tmpAbC8uL TO /tmp/ansible-tmp-1480399947.38-137956022601151/uri
hazelcast EXEC chmod a+r /tmp/ansible-tmp-1480399947.38-137956022601151/uri
hazelcast EXEC /bin/sh -c 'sudo -H -S -n -u app /bin/sh -c '"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-cciaazzdblahblahblahdufmpuhe; LANG=en_US.UTF-8 HTTP_PROXY=proxy.com LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8 HTTPS_PROXY=proxy.com no_proxy=proxy.com http_proxy=proxy.com https_proxy=proxy.com NO_PROXY=proxy.comLC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/python /tmp/ansible-tmp-1480399947.38-137956022601151/uri'"'"''
hazelcast EXEC rm -f -r /tmp/ansible-tmp-1480399947.38-137956022601151/ > /dev/null 2>&1
fatal: [hazelcast]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "content": "", "content_length": "0", "failed": true, "invocation": {"module_args": {"HEADER_Cookie": "JSESSIONID=dq0hzdvm2xm91r4h6eyef1l48;Path=/mancenter;HttpOnly", "backup": null, "body": "operation=savelicense_getLicenceInfo&key=ENTERPRISELicense123412341234123412341234123412341234", "body_format": "raw", "content": null, "creates": null, "delimiter": null, "dest": null, "directory_mode": null, "follow": false, "follow_redirects": "safe", "force": null, "force_basic_auth": false, "group": null, "method": "POST", "mode": null, "owner": null, "password": null, "regexp": null, "remote_src": null, "removes": null, "return_content": true, "selevel": null, "serole": null, "setype": null, "seuser": null, "src": null, "status_code": [200], "timeout": 30, "url": "http://internal-aws.elb.amazonaws.com:8080/mancenter/main.do", "user": null, "validate_certs": true}, "module_name": "uri"}, "location": "http://internal-aws.elb.amazonaws.com:8080/mancenter/login.jsp", "msg": "Status code was not [200]", "redirected": false, "server": "Jetty(8.y.z-SNAPSHOT)", "status": 302}
```

EDIT:
Thanks for that solution emre. Using curl was the way to go.

I tried a few more times with the uri ansible module. But no dice... must be something under the hood going on.

Since your curl's hit the nail on the head, I just wrapped this in the ansible command module instead of using the uri module to construct the calls.
I chdir to /tmp to ensure I have write access for the cookie file.

```
- name: Login to management
  shell: "curl -X POST http://{{ hazelcastmanagement_dns }}:8080/mancenter/j_spring_security_check -d "j_username={{ hazelcastmanagement_user}}" -d "j_password={{ hazelcastmanagement_password }}" -c cookies.file
  args:
    chdir: /tmp

- name: Login to management
  shell: "curl -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -X POST http://{{ hazelcastmanagement_dns }}:8080/mancenter/main.do?operation=savelicense -d 'key={{ hazelcast_licence }}' -b cookies.file
  args:
    chdir: /tmp
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about Ansible, but using cUrl you can log in and set the license key as follows:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8083/mancenter/j_spring_security_check -d "j_username=emre" -d "j_password=Password1" -c cookies.file

curl -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -X POST http://localhost:8083/mancenter/main.do?operation=savelicense -d 'key=aaaa' -b cookies.file
```

Note that you need to log in with an admin user and the license key you provide needs to be correct for the server to return `200`.

**Edit:**

With Hazelcast Management Center version 3.9.3, a new system property to configure the license was introduced. See the [release notes for version 3.9.3](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/management-center/rn/index.html#3-9-3) and [the relevant section on the latest reference manual](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/management-center/3.11.2/manual/html/index.html#starting-with-a-license) for details.

Comment: Thanks for that lead. So I tried a few more times with the uri ansible module. But no dice... must be something under the hood going on.

I wrapped that in ansible command module and it works a treat.
Added my ansible to the question as it was too long for comment.

Comment: BTW, please note that this is *not* a public API that is guaranteed to be maintained in the future releases.

Comment: Totally. At the time of this implementation Hazelcast had not published API's for mancenter and their recommended approach to configuring it was manual human via gui (Not great if your spinning up and tearing down environments). This could and probably will change with future releases (hopefully).